# How to make a very fluffy croissant?

Tags: pastry

I've been trying to master the croissant for the last 3 months, and right now I really want to have the honeycomb view inside of it. Unfortunately, this was the maximum that I have reached:

[image]

How to come to this point?

[image]

PS: Right now doing a recipe that I make a dough (flour, water, sugar, salt, yeast), put in the fridge. After 1h, laminate the dough, chill, laminate again. Let it overnight before final stretch and croissant shape.

Let it rise for 2 hours before going to oven.

Comment: Those look pale, your oven may not be hot enough.

Comment: Yeah, I will let it more time there

Comment: That's not necessarily right, what **temperature** is your oven?

Comment: 180c. Should I bump to 200c?

Comment: Yes, you need to turn it up, I bake croissants at 210c (non-fan), then turn down to 200 half-way through. If they are getting too brown too soon turn it down to 190c. If you want to keep it simple set the oven to 205c.